# Objects showing up in render

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation

I have a smoke domain showing up in my sampled render. I'm not sure if it will show up in rendered or is just in sampled.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As long as the camera button is un-clicked(as you have it now) It should not appear in a render, it will however be visible in the 3D view unless you un-click the button that looks like an eye. Also, because you're in cycles, you can just do a light render with like 10 samples and easily see a low quality image of what your creation looks like so far.

Comment: If you disable the renderability of the smoke domain, the smoke simulation will not render, it will only be visible in the 3d viewport.